# Analyzing $T$-$S$ diagrams

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

[image]

This is the motivation behind my question; what would the longest line therein translate into on a $p$-$V$ curve? It is evident that the horizontal line is an isothermal process and the vertical line is an adiabatic (isentropic) process. But what kind of process is represented by the third line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the perfect ideal gas model $P v = R T$, you can:

1. write the parametric expression of the line representing the transformation in the $T-S$ plane
   \begin{equation}
      T = T_0 + \frac{T_1 - T_0}{s_1 - s_0} (s - s_0) = a + b s \ , \quad \text{or} \quad  s = \alpha + \beta T
   \end{equation}
2. exploit

   - the $1^{st}$ principle of thermodynamics,  $de = Tds - P dv$
   - the equation of the ideal gas $Pv = RT$ and the expression of the internal energy $e = c_v T$ with constant $c_v$, s.t. $de = c_v dT$

   to write
   \begin{equation}
     ds = c_v \dfrac{dT}{T} + R \dfrac{dv}{v} = \dots = c_v  \dfrac{dP}{P} + c_P \dfrac{dv}{v} \ ,
   \end{equation}
   having used the relation $\frac{dT}{T} = \frac{dP}{P} + \frac{dv}{v}$ (that you can easily derive as the differential of the ideal gas equation with constant $R$)
3. compare the differential of the expression of the entropy as a function of temperature provided at point 1., $ds = \beta d T$ (and using the relation linking the differential of $T$ with the differentials of $P$ and $v$), with the one obtained at point 2.,
   \begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
     ds & = \beta \left( \dfrac{dP}{P} + \dfrac{dv}{v} \right) \\
     ds & = c_v  \dfrac{dP}{P} + c_P \dfrac{dv}{v} \ ,
   \end{aligned}
   \end{equation}
   to get a differential relation linking $P$ and $v$,
   \begin{equation}
     (c_v - \beta)\dfrac{dP}{P} + (c_P - \beta) \dfrac{dv}{v} = 0 \ ,
   \end{equation}
   and by integration,
   \begin{equation}
     \dfrac{P}{P_0} = \left(\frac{v}{v_0}\right)^{-\frac{c_P - \beta}{c_v - \beta}}
   \end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'm an undergraduate third year and no expert of thermodynamics, but I wanted to have a trial.
If you are expecting viewers to come up with an answer like "instant adiabatic expansion", "Joule-Thompson expansion", "isenthalpic process" etc. I believe the process you sketched in T-s diagram matches with no such well-documented process. You can evaluate formulations to describe it as @basics did for you, but it is more convenient to rationalize it in terms of energy & work and accept that the subprocess you asked for is just a consequence of two well known process types: isentropic and isothermal processes. 
In your case, there are three steps but the third step can be deemed as the result of the applied steps or consumption of the accumulated energy from preceding steps in the system.
Let's assume the system is a monoatomic ideal gas.
Firstly, it goes under isothermal compression, I concluded that it is compression since entropy can be viewed as a function of temperature and volume,
\begin{equation}
{\Delta}S=nC_V\ln{\frac{T_2}{T_1}}-nR\ln{\frac{V_1}{V_2}}\\
{\Delta}S_T=(-nR\ln{\frac{V_1}{V_2}})_T\\
\end{equation}
Since entropy is decreasing for the first step, the right-hand side of the above equation must be negative, and $\ln{\frac{V_1}{V_2}}$ must be positive, thus $V_2<V_1$, i.e., compression. Forget about our ideal gas assumption for one second and imagine a real system: at constant temperature, in order to compress a system you have to do work on it and this would cause system to emit some amount of heat and to steeply scale pressure up, since this is the only way to satisfy all the conditions.
Now back to our ideal gas, at the second step there is an adiabatic (isentropic indeed) compression. I got that 'compression' result by the following reasoning: since the subprocess is isentropic, by using $\frac{T_2}{T_1}=(\frac{V_1}{V_2})^{\frac{R}{C_V}}$ one can easily see that for a constant & known initial temperature and volume $T_1, V_1$; since temperature $T_2$ increases, volume $V_2$ will decrease. Therefore this is also a subprocess of compression.
Again, forget about ideal gas and turn back to reality: for an adiabatic compression to take place you have to provide work to the system but there are no heat emissions (or in negligibly small amounts) this time. Thus the total accumulated energy within the system is the isothermal compression work plus adiabatic compression work minus heat emitted in the isothermal subprocess. 
After that point the system is going to use this total energy to return its initial state. 
To sum up, we can simply say that the whole process is a hypothetical compression-expansion process that has an isothermal compression subprocess, an adiabatic compression subprocess, and an expansion process.